# Where should Automapper references go in multi-tiered application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper, automapper-collections-ef-core

I have a web solution which includes a web UI, web api layer, service objects, and a data layer which encapsulates repositories (sometimes using a Unit of Work pattern) and Entity Framework entities.  My web service is returning JSON which I'm deserializing within the UI controller like this:

```
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(endpoint);

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<anyTypeHere>(await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

My web api layer calls various "services" (all represented as their own library project - ie: Accounting Service, EnrollmentService, CalendarService). Within each service object is code to access data entities thru Repositories:

```
// returns entity object
var customer = UnitOfWork.PatientRepository.GetCustomerById();
```

I'd like to use a tool like AutoMapper to map entity objects to dto/domain objects thus returning the dto objects back to the UI caller.

My question are:

1. Where should I add Automapper reference and mapping code?  (ie: WebApi, service project, repository layer, etc...)
2. Should I create a separate library that contains the DTO objects and reference this in my UI client as well as api and service layer(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create class Library project for your DTOs like YourProject.Dtos and transfer all your dtos to this project. then in another project(YourProject.Mapping) create  interface:

```
 public interface IMapperProfile
{
}
```

use this interface for mapping signature like:

```
  public class AddressMapping : Profile, IMapperProfile
{
    public AddressMapping()
    {
        CreateMap<AddressDto, Address>(MemberList.None).ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

AddressRepositories methods  must be like this:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<AddressDto>> GetAllAsync( CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var result = await _entity.AsNoTracking().ToListSync();
        return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<AddressDto>>(result);
    }
```

now you can register Automapper in your api or ui startup class :

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(IMapperProfile));
```

Comment: Is there also a requirement to map the dto objects returned from the api webservice to the ui model objects? OR should my domain (model) objects be same dto's you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: you can use the same domain model dto, also you can have your ui domain model and deserialize returned api dto to ui dto without requirement to automapper mapping config

Comment: Very consistent with what I'm already doing.  Much appreciated.  I'll accept this as a valid answer.